# Conditionally add virtual desktop in Openbox

Tags: desktop, openbox

I am trying to make Openbox add a new desktop upon moving the active window to the left of the first desktop. Moving the window from any other desktop should just move the window.

The config I use is as follows:

```
<keybind key="S-W-A-Left">
  <action name="if">
    <query>
      <desktop>0</desktop>
    </query>
    <then>
      <action name="AddDesktop">
        <where>current</where>
      </action>
    </then>
  </action>
  <action name="SendToDesktopLeft">
    <dialog>no</dialog>
    <wrap>no</wrap>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Moving the window works as expected. The problem is that the If-clause seems to allways succeed - Openbox adds a new desktop, regardless of which desktop the active window originates from.

What am I missing!?

Comment: I managed to post config that did not match the config I was actually using. I had `<desktop>0</desktop>`, not `<desktop>1</desktop>`. The question has been updated to match reality. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first desktop has the number 1 so `<desktop>1</desktop>` is what you want. `<desktop>0</desktop>` is probably supposed to match all desktops.

You should also note that the [SendToDesktop](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions#SendToDesktop) section of the on the [Openbox wiki](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions),  does not mention any `<dialog>` option, in fact it does not mention any method at all that you could use to prevent the OSD from showing.